# Solving $Y_t$ = $e^{-\alpha t}X_t$ using Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

G'day
I am trying to solve $Y_t$ = $e^{-\alpha t}X_t$, where $dX_t = \alpha X_tdt + \sigma_tdW_t$ using Ito's lemma.

- Defining f(t, X) = $e^{-\alpha t}X$. $\frac{df(t,X)}{dt}$ = $-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X$;  $\frac{df(t,X)}{dX}$ = $e^{-\alpha t}$.
- Using Ito's lemma:
  $dY_t = -\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X_t(dt) +  e^{-\alpha t}(dX_t)$
- Substituting dt and dXt gives:
- = $-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X_t( \alpha X_tdt) + e^{-\alpha t}(\alpha X_tdt + \sigma_tdW_t$)
- Calculating: $e^{-\alpha t}(\alpha X_tdt + \sigma_tdW_t)$ = $\alpha e^{-\alpha t}dt + \sigma_t e^{-\alpha t}dW_t$
- Moving in to the first part where I think the problem lies in finding the solution:
- $-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X_t( \alpha X_tdt)$ = $- \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha}X^{2}_tdt$. I think that this step is wrong because no matter what I do, I can't seem to conclude with the given solution:
- = $\sigma_t e^{-\alpha t}dW_t$

Can someone explain the last steps and finish what I started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite following your derivation, but on the fourth line, I don't see how/why you are replacing $dt$ with $\alpha X_{t} dt$ and on the fifth line, when you multiply out the factor, it looks like $X_{t}$ is lost in the first term.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes: $-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X_t( \alpha X_tdt)$ should be only $-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}X_t(dt)$ right? Can you explain why we don't need to to multiply with the first term as there is a dt in it? Yes, regarding the lost term X, it helps. If you can explain my misconception of $\alpha X_tdt$ versus $dt$ this question is solved.

Comment: @sc_ams: The answer to your first question is 'Yes'. I don't understand your second question. In the line you say: "Using Ito's lemma", you only have to substitute $dX_t,$ the term 'dt' is just 'dt'.

Comment: @UBM, so when taking the derivative with respect to t, you don't have to substitute any term? Ever? Just multiple with ${dt}$ and that's it?

Comment: @sc_ams: yes, exactly.